# JQuery - Context Menu for Newly Created Element

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

Im using [JQuery Context Menu plugin](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/).

When the document is ready, I have `contextMenu` for `img` elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').contextMenu({
        menu: 'photoMenu'
    },function(action, el, pos) {
        //some function

    });
});
```

I am going to add dynamically `img` element:

```
$img = $('<img />');
```

How to bind `contextMenu` for the newly created `img` element. It should be the same with the above? Should I create a function call it? Or there are other easy way for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please close the question, if you got the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are attaching your `contextMenu` in your document ready function. You should create the `contextMenu` after the image is created.

So just update your code to

```
$img = $('<img />');

$img.contextMenu({
        menu: 'photoMenu'
    },function(action, el, pos) {
        //some function

    });
```

**Note:** You have to make sure that you are creating the `contextMenu` after creating the image object.

Comment: I have existing `img` element when page load.

Comment: In that case don't delete the current contextMenu code in $(document).ready.